# integration of polynomial * exponential of polynomial

Tags: integration, polynomials, exponential-function

I have the following problem:

$$\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} (ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)\exp{(fx^4 + gx^3 + hx^2 + ix + j)}\ dx$$

$b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j\in\mathbb{R}$. One can assume the final value of the integral is finite even if $\alpha\rightarrow-\infty$ and $\beta\rightarrow\infty$ (the polynomial coefficient $a,f<0$ ).

Does it has a closed form solution ?
Is there any **special** numerical method to evaluate this ?

Comment: Very, very little hope ! $\int e^{a+b x+c x^2+d x^3} \, dx$ does not show explicit solution (all coefficients being $\neq 0$). Don't waste your time and go to numerical integration.

Comment: Have you tried with lower degree polynomials and seen whether anything can be done?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Don't just remove the polynomial factor. It may change things drastically. For instance, $e^{-x^2}$ famously cannot be antidifferentiated while $xe^{-x^2}$ is an introductory exercise in substitution.

Comment: Nonetheless, Claude's statement means that a general formula for all a,b,c,d, etc. is unavailable

Comment: Thanks, this saved me few hours on internet searching integrals

Comment: Note: it's inadvisable to use $e$ both to refer to the base of the natural logarithm, and as an arbitrary real number. Consider using $\exp$ instead, or perhaps denoting the two polynomials by $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Thanks, corrected.

Comment: I don't think there is an antiderivative if the $p(x)$ has degree higher than 1 (where $p(x)$ is the exponent